# What is the reason that the vibrating body gradually acquires the frequency of the external periodic force in forced vibration?

Tags: forces, acoustics, frequency, resonance, vibrations

> When an external periodic force is applied on a vibrating body the body no longer vibrates with its own natural frequency but it gradually acquires the frequency of the applied periodic force.

I don't understand why the vibrating body would  gradually acquire  the frequency of the applied periodic force. I have been searching for this answer since quite a long time(I have looked overe the internet,books,etc). But failed to understand why it happens so. Could someone please explain  the cause of this phenomenon intuitively .

Answer (score 3):

The statement *When an external periodic force is applied on a vibrating body . . . . .* needs to be changed slightly.

Suppose a simple system which had one natural frequency of oscillation.
Further suppose that system is made to oscillate by displacing it from its static equilibrium position.
The system will oscillate and with damping present those oscillations will die down after a time.

Now couple the system to a device which is oscillation at at frequency $f$  - the driver.
The initial motion of the system will consist of two components often called the transient and the steady state.
The transient component is at a frequency of the system as though there was not a device forcing it to oscillation and that transient motion dies down to zero with time because the system is damped.
The steady state component is at a frequency of the driver and the amplitude of that motion does not change with time so that is the motion observed after the transient motion has died away.

This graph illustrates such a behaviour and is taken from the Mathematics SE - [How to graph for transient state and steady state](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359270/how-to-graph-for-transient-state-and-steady-state).

[image]

To recap.  The motion of a system which being driven is complex at first being the sum of motions at two frequencies but after a time one of those (the transient) dies down to zero leaving a constant amplitude motion at the frequency of the driver (steady state).

So perhaps?

*When an external periodic force is applied on a vibrating body, the body xx xxxxxx vibrates with its own natural frequency **with a motion which is damped** xxx xx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx **and finally reaches a constant amplitude state at** the frequency of the applied periodic force.*

[The xxx are to illustrate words which I have removed from the original text].